# asp:ListBox with DataBind RequiredFieldValidator issue

Tags: data-binding, listbox, requiredfieldvalidator

Here is my code:

## Issue with ListBox and RequiredFieldValidator with DataBind

C# Code:
lstCategories.DataSource = getList("Categories");
lstCategories.DataBind();

Categories have been populated in ListBox, however, I see error message even though I selected the value from Listbox. How do I make it work for RequiredFieldValidator ?

Comment: Looks lke aspx code is missing, let me edit

Comment: <asp:ListBox id="lstCategories" style="width: 100%;" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataTextField="Descr" DataValueField="Value" />
                
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="lstCategories" InitialValue="" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please select at least one item." />

Comment: Always giving error : Please select at least one item